# How to make a link in a Telerik MVC grid template column send a post to an action

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-mvc

There is a lot going on here.

I have a Telerik MVC grid with the following templated column:

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid((IEnumerable<User)Model.Data)
  .Name("UsersGrid")
  .DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(c => c.UserName))
  .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Server()
  .Columns(c =>
  {
    c.Bound(r => r.FullName).Title("");
    c.Bound(r => r.UserName).Title("");
    c.Template(
      @<text>
        @if(@item.Status == "Pending")
        {
           @Html.ActionLink("Resend Invite", "ResendInvite", new { Email = @item.UserName, FirstName = @item.FullName }, new { @class = "reesendInviteLink" })
        }
      </text>
    ).Title("Link").HtmlAttributes(new { Style = "text-align: right;" });
  }));
```

Now I know ActionLink will not call a post action so I'm doing the following with jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(".resendInviteLink").click(function (e) {
      var url = e.currentTarget.href;
      $.post(url);
   });
});
```

The Action method I am trying to call looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ResendInvite(UserVM user)
{
   //....Do Something
}
```

When I debug the jquery everything goes well until I reach the $.post and then it fails saying that it cannot find the ResendInvite action on the controller. In a way I think it makes sense since the ActionLink is looking for a Get, not a Post.

So how can I create a link on the grid that will:
1. Get the email and the user's name from the Telerik grid.
2. Call a post action method with the correct paameters.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that although you've subsribed on the link's `click event` with Jquery, the link's original `click event` still fires a Get request which fails.

You need to use the  [preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) method

```
$(".resendInviteLink").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = e.currentTarget.href;
    $.post(url);
});
```

Or `return false` form the event handler:

```
$(".resendInviteLink").click(function(e) {
    var url = e.currentTarget.href;
    $.post(url);
    return false;
});
```